# Find all occurrences of a regex pattern in a line

Tags: java, regex

My String is like this (one single line):

```
String input = "Details of all persons. Person=details=John Smith-age-22; Person=details=Alice Kohl-age-23; Person=details=Ram Mohan-city-Dallas; Person=details=Michael Jack-city-Boston;"
```

I want to find out using regex matching all the persons with its details (basically text from details upto the char prior to semicolon). I am interested in finding:

```
details=John Smith-age-22
details=Alice Kohl-age-23
details=Ram Mohan-city-Dallas
details=Michael Jack-city-Boston
```

Can someone tell me how to do this ? Sorry, I could not find any example like that over the net. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You can try this code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "Details of all persons. Person=details=John Smith-age-22; Person=details=Alice Kohl-age-23; Person=details=Ram Mohan-city-Dallas; Person=details=Michael Jack-city-Boston;";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=Person=).*?(?=;)");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        String str = matcher.group();
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

**No assertion**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "Details of all persons. Person=details=John Smith-age-22; Person=details=Alice Kohl-age-23; Person=details=Ram Mohan-city-Dallas; Person=details=Michael Jack-city-Boston;";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("Person=.*?;");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        String str = matcher.group();
        System.out.println(str.substring(7, str.length()-1));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply, this helps! 
However, I was not aware of lookahead/lookbehind before. Though I went through the doc now, but I want to know if there is any other way as well (other than lookahead etc) ?

Also can you explain why we need the second '?' char in the pattern ? How does that help ?

Comment: In `.*?`, the `?`is key-word of `Reluctant quantifiers`. Please read the help doc of "Reluctant quantifiers".  If have not the `?`, the result will be `details=John Smith-age-22; Person=details=Alice Kohl-age-23; Person=details=Ram Mohan-city-Dallas; Person=details=Michael Jack-city-Boston`.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you will find it easiest if you put the fields you are looking for into groups so that you can extract the details you want.

Something like:

```
Pattern personPattern = Pattern.compile("Person=details=(\\w+)-(age-\\d+|city-\\w+); ");

Matcher matcher = personPattern.match(input);
while (matcher.find()) {
    String name = matcher.group(1);
    String field = matcher.group(2);
    ...
}
```